# CSS and Javascript dropdown navigation not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website navigation should have three main links on the left ("Menu", "Coffee", and "Our Story"), and two on the right ("Wholesale" and "Talk to Us"). The first two ("Menu" and "Coffee") should be dropdown menus, however when I click "Menu" the dropdown menu only *sometimes* appears. When I click "Coffee" the dropdown *sometimes* appears too, but it shows the dropdown links for "Menu" instead of it's own.

My first thought is that maybe I need two separate functions for "Menu" and "Coffee"? Is there a way to properly display the dropdown links on click? And can I also somehow display the dropdown on hover?
Thank you in advanced.

HTML:

```
  <nav class ="navbar">
    <ul class="left-nav">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><li>Menu</li></button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Drinks</a>
          <a href="#">Pastries</a>
          <a href="#">Catering</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><li>Coffee</li></button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Blends</a>
          <a href="#">Beanie's Brand</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#"><li>Our Story</li></a>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-nav">
      <a href="#"><li>Wholesale</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Talk To Us</li></a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar ul {
  top: 170px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
.left-nav {
  flex: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: left;
  left: 0px;
}
.right-nav {
  flex: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  right: 50px;
}
.navbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  /* color: rgb(255, 180, 148); */
  color: white;
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif;
  font-weight: 530;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar a:hover {
  color: hsl(39, 92%, 70%);
}
/* Dropdown Navigation */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0); 
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif;
  font-weight: 530;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropntn:focus {
  color: hsl(39, 92%, 70%);
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
}
.show {display:block;}
```

Javascript:

```
   /* Toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

   // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one element with same id on a page, you should target the dropdown differently:

```
function myFunction(element) {
    element.parentNode.querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn"><li>Coffee</li></button>
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about the id's rule. Thank you! Do you suggest that's literally how I should write it?